# Botched Apache config on macOS Sierra - Virtual hosts will not work

Tags: macos, apache-http-server

I’m installing the whole LAMP stack through Homebrew (Apache, PHP, MySQL, Dnsmasq).

Here’s a brief summary of the config:

```
ServerName localhost

Listen 80

DocumentRoot "/Users/your_user/Sites"
<Directory "/Users/your_user/Sites">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

With just these, everything works fine.

On the next part when I try to add virtual host using a config I know to have worked in the past, I encounter errors.

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/mod_vhost_alias.so

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/elzi/Sites
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName dev
  ServerAlias *.dev
  VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/elzi/Sites/%-2+
</VirtualHost>
```

At this point I’m not even worried about PHP/MySQL/DNSMASQ. I just need *one* of my virtualhost configs to work first. Using the bottom rule I should be able to access any site in my `~/Sites` folder, provided I make an entry for them in my hosts file.

I can access site at `http://localhost` and see an index of whatever I set the `DocumentRoot` (or `VirtualDocument`) root to be, but I cannot access wildcard `ServerAlias`. For example,

`http://test.dev` does not resolve in Apache, despite:

- It existing in my host file.
- Being able to ping it.

I’m starting to think the problem is not strictly Apache related? Maybe DNS/IPv6 issues?

Here's a dump of `netstat -amp tcp | grep 80`

```
tcp4       0      0  192.168.0.108.49632    151.101.193.69.80      ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  192.168.0.108.49608    151.101.193.69.80      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0  ::1.49567              ::1.80                 CLOSE_WAIT 
tcp4       0      0  192.168.0.108.49566    192.168.0.101.8060     CLOSE_WAIT
tcp46      0      0  *.80                   *.*                    LISTEN
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.18800        *.*                    LISTEN
```

Output of `sudoapachectl -v`

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix)
Server built:   Dec 22 2016 18:07:11
```

Output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Output of `brew services list`

```
Name    Status  User Plist
httpd24 started elzi /Users/elzi/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd24.plist
jack    started elzi /Users/elzi/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.jack.plist
mongodb started elzi /Users/elzi/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
mysql   started elzi /Users/elzi/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
php70   started elzi /Users/elzi/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php70.plist
```

Output of `sudo apachectl -S`

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server localhost (/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:3)
         port 80 namevhost localhost (/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:3)
         port 80 namevhost dev (/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:8)
                 wild alias *.dev
ServerRoot: "/usr/local/opt/httpd24"
Main DocumentRoot: "/Users/elzi/Sites"
Main ErrorLog: "/usr/local/var/log/apache2/error_log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/usr/local/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/usr/local/var/run/apache2/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="elzi" id=501
Group: name="staff" id=20
```

Comment: Please edit your question to be very specific about what you mean by "will not work" and "I encounter errors".  What did you try, what results did you expect, and what results did you get?

Comment: So, if I'm interpreting your config file right, you want connections to unknown host names, plus "localhost" and "dev" to use `/Users/elzi/Sites`, but you want connections to `example.dev` to use `/Users/elzi/sites/example/` but connections to `www.example.dev` should use `/Users/elzi/Sites/www.example`. Is that right? Can you give an example of what you tried and what happened?

Comment: @Spiff edited for clarity. Sorry about that. That is exactly right, except I'm not concerned about `www.example.dev` resolving, just `example.dev`

This was a config that worked fine with apache 2.2. It's straight up magic when it works, I just create a new folder in my ~/Sites  and I can automatically access it with the wildcard * rule and the `%-2+` string formatting. Now nothing resolves. Even when I manually add a VirtualHost rule directly to a folder it does not resolve.

Comment: @elzi how did you get it to work?

Comment: @LukasKawerau I should prob just delete this question since the config I ended up with is quite different than what my original post entails, but I more or less followed this guide: https://echo.co/blog/os-x-1010-yosemite-local-development-environment-apache-php-and-mysql-homebrew with two important differences - 1) Supplement apache version to use 2.4 and installed with `brew install --with privledged-ports`  2) Do not bother with installing his `co.echo.httpdfwd.plist` launch daemon since 2.4 can use privledged ports. and 2a) 80 instead of 8080 where applicable.